# ecommerce website "add to cart" button it show message Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\online shop\index.php</b> on line <b>147</b><br />

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I want to add "add to cart" button in my index.php page under every products. But "add to cart" button it show message:  Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\online shop\index.php** on line **147**
.
need to solve this.

**index.php**

```
 <!--Product Show Start-->  
 <div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom ">
 <div class="container"></br>
 <div id="result_div" class="result_div"></div>
<h1><b>New Products:</b></h1>
<div class="row">

 <?php
    $per_page = 8;
        $p = new Product();
        $data = $p->View();

        if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $start = 0;
            $end = $per_page;
        }
        else
        {
            $start = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $per_page;
            $end = $_GET['page'] * $per_page;
        }
        if($end>count($data))
        {
            $end = count($data);
        }

        for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i++)
        {
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3" >
          <div class="thumbnail" style="box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px  #888888;">
            <a href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i][0];?>">
            <img style="width:200px;height:150px" src="image/<?php print  $data[$i][5]?>"/></a>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i] [0];?>"><?php print $data[$i][1]?></a></h4>
              <h4>Price: <?php print $data[$i][2]?> TK</h4>


            </div>

            <div class="space-ten"></div>
            <div class="btn-ground text-center">

                <a class="btn btn-success" href="user/add_to_cart.php?id=<?php print $_GET['id'];?>">Add to cart</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary"  href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i][0];?>">View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="space-ten"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
     <?php
    }
   ?>       

 </div>
  <!--pagination start-->
  <style>
 .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span { border-radius: 50%   !important;margin: 0 5px;}
 </style>
  <ul class="pagination">
          <li><a href="#">«</a></li>

          <li><?php
                $p = 1;
                for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i = $i+$per_page)
                {
                    echo "<a href=\"index.php?page={$p}\" class='page'>".   $p ."</a>";
                    $p++;
                }
            ?></li>

          <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
        </ul>
  <!--pagination end-->         
  </div>

   </div>
  <!--Product Show End-->
```

**add_to_cart.php**

```
<?php
require_once("../dataAccessLayer/dalSession.php");

Session::Start();

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $c=0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($_SESSION['cart']); $i++)
    {   
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$i] == $_GET['id'])
        {
            $c++;
            break;
        }   
    }
    if($c == 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['id'];
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = 1;
    }

  }
  else
  {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['qty'][] = 1;     
  }

  }
  header("Location: details.php?id={$_GET['id']}");

 ?>
```

**cart.php**

```
 <?php
 require_once("../dataAccessLayer/dalSession.php");
 require_once("../dataAccessLayer/dalComment.php");
 require_once("../dataAccessLayer/dalProduct.php");
 ?>

<?php
                     $pro = new Product();
                     $pro->product_id = $_GET['id'];
                     $r = $pro->SelectById();
                    ?>
```

Comment: And how did you try to develop it? And whats the Problem?

Comment: You actually need to explain to us what your issue is. If you've already done it in one page, do the same on the other page? And it seems like the "Add to cart" button is triggering some Ajax? Show us _all_ the relevant code, _explain_ your issue, show what you've tried and where it goes wrong. We're not mind readers.

Comment: I want to add to cart button in my index page under every product

Comment: We know what you want, but we don't know why you can't do it. Where are you failing? You said that you've done it on the product page, why not do it the same way?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-success" href="add_to_cart.php?id=<?php 
  print $_GET['id'];?>">Add to cart</a> in my product details.php page it is working fine. but index.php same code not working properly

Comment: ...and what does _"not working properly"_ mean? What happens? Error messages? Wrong product get's logged? Computer catches on fire? _What is the issue?_ Btw, I don't see that code in your index. I only see a "Add to cart" link without any `href` at all. Well, I've tried... I'm out...

Comment: now check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just replace this code in your index.php**

```
<!--Product Show Start-->   
 <div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom ">
 <div class="container"></br>
 <div id="result_div" class="result_div"></div>
<h1><b>New Products:</b></h1>
<div class="row">

 <?php
    $per_page = 8;
        $p = new Product();
        $data = $p->View();

        if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $start = 0;
            $end = $per_page;
        }
        else
        {
            $start = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $per_page;
            $end = $_GET['page'] * $per_page;
        }
        if($end>count($data))
        {
            $end = count($data);
        }

        for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i++)
        {
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3" >
          <div class="thumbnail" style="box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px  #888888;">
            <a href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i][0];?>">
            <img style="width:200px;height:150px" src="image/<?php print  $data[$i][5]?>"/></a>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i] [0];?>"><?php print $data[$i][1]?></a></h4>
              <h4>Price: <?php print $data[$i][2]?> TK</h4>


            </div>

            <div class="space-ten"></div>
            <div class="btn-ground text-center">


              <?php
                    $_GET['id']=$data[$i][0];
                     $pro = new Product();
                     $pro->product_id = $_GET['id'];
                     $r = $pro->SelectById();

                     ?>

                <a class="btn btn-success" href="user/add_to_cart.php?id=<?php print $_GET['id'];?>">Add to cart</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary"  href="user/details.php?id=<?php print $data[$i][0];?>">View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="space-ten"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
     <?php
    }
   ?>       

 </div>
  <!--pagination start-->
  <style>
 .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span { border-radius: 50%   !important;margin: 0 5px;}
 </style>
  <ul class="pagination">
          <li><a href="#">«</a></li>

          <li><?php
                $p = 1;
                for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i = $i+$per_page)
                {
                    echo "<a href=\"index.php?page={$p}\" class='page'>".   $p ."</a>";
                    $p++;
                }
            ?></li>

          <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
        </ul>
  <!--pagination end-->         
  </div>

   </div>
  <!--Product Show End-->
```